# Converting stdout stream to html (add <br> on linebreaks)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm trying to take some console output text and render it through django/js in a modal on my site. When printing the console output the line breaks work fine, but when rendered on the site it shows them all as one line. I tried replacing all the \n with `<br>` but it didn't seem to have any effect.  The `<br>` are shown in line as plain text. Any thoughts on a better way to do this/why this isn't working in the first place?

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

# Save the old stdout
old_stdout = sys.stdout

# Save the stdout to variable
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

... # Do some processing that generates console text

# Reset the to the old stdout
sys.stdout = old_stdout

# Get the stdout
processing_std_out = mystdout.getvalue()

# Replace all the linebreaks with <br>
# This is the important part
processing_std_out = processing_std_out.replace("\n","<br>")

# return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'console_output':processing_std_out}), content_type="application/json")
```

The js is this:

```
input_modal.find('.modal-body').text('Analysis complete'+response.console_output)
```

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: This code does not process any input. And why are you replacing the stdout? If you have a web service, try processing the http response, not stdout,

Comment: What is at the ends of the lines before and after the replace? If you search for \n without replacing it, do you get any hits? Have you tried using </p><p> instead of <br>? (You would have to force a <p> onto the beginning and a </p> onto the end, of course.) Finally, what are the next few things you do with `processing_std_out` after the replace?

Comment: I updated the code to make it more clear. This actually seems to work on my local console...but doesn't seem to work through the js snippet.

Comment: It is also common to use <pre>[console output]</pre> when displaying console data as it automatically use a monospace font and it does not force you to add <br> everywhere.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure if I should be updating the modal with .text, .val, or maybe something else entirely?
The pre tag renders in plaintext:
Analysis complete<pre>... </pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake, I should have been passing the HTML, not the text. Also, adding pre tags to the text is much simpler than replacing all \n

```
input_modal.find('.modal-body').html('Analysis complete'+response.console_output)
```